# Automatic scrolling text right to left in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Hey I want to make text scroll from right to left in a div i have. I want this to happen automatically and at a constant flow.

Now when i first started with HTML the  tag was used to do this, I've looked around a few websites and it seems that this tag still seems to be going. My question is really if this is the best way of achieving this affect or is there a better way of doing it? for example, javascript,Jquery and/or css Maybe even something in HTML5?

This shows what i am looking - http://www.gftuk.com/

Notice the scrolling stops when the user hovers over the text.

Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I think the best way to achieve this would be to use jquery. There are a few plugins out there which do the job nicely.

Comment: I just found "simplyScroll" plugin for Jquery. Do you know of any good ones you would suggest?

Comment: I would write one myself rather than use a plugin. But if you can't do that then I would suggest trying a few from here http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/marquee to see what works best with your project

Answer (score 2):

```
<marquee>hello world</marquee>
```

Comment: So that is the best way of doing this? Does this tag provide any attributes so i can control the speed?

Comment: `<marquee scrollamount=1 scrolldelay=500>test</marquee>`

Comment: It is the best way. It is supported in old browsers, works when javascript is disabled, makes your files smaller (saves bytes), screenreader friendly, search engine friendly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatic with "scroll" text ( structure of DOM is not complex) .

```
<marquee>This text will scroll from right to left</marquee>
```

But you will see with "marquee" the scroll is not smooth.
So you can use simplyScroll plugin

```
http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/
```

( I see it in this code of your link : http://www.gftuk.com/. in next time, please open dev tools or firebugs and see source code of any pages when you want to have the same effects )
Hope it helps you